# How do I get chunks of n points from pandas DataFrame to plot their mean

Tags: pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I have a csv file of around 6000 rows and I want to plot the mean of always n (75) points, starting from row x (49) to row y (3266).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(
    r'C:\Intel\Solinst-cleaned up\yellow.csv',
    skiprows=13,
    encoding='unicode_escape',
    parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']]
    )


x = df['Date_Time'][49:124]  # First 75 points I want the mean for
y = df['Mlevel'][49:124]

plt.plot(x, y, 'lightblue', label='Normal day')
```

So how do I get the following chunks of 75 points each up to row 3266?

Comment: You could try `x=df1['Date_Time'][49:3267:75]`? The format is `[first:stop:step]`; it ends when `x>=stop`.

Comment: Is striding as @JohanC mentioned what you are looking for? Or are you rather trying to take chunks of 75 points each, then plotting the mean of the chunks?

Comment: Thank you John but I do not want every 75th point to be plotted. I want every 75 points (tidal cycle) to be plotted in the same figure. So something around 42 plots.

Comment: @JanJoswig Yes I want chunks of 75 points but I am having trouble using a for loop.

Comment: 3267-49 is not close to a multiple of 75: where does the upper bound come from considering `around 6000 rows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some minimal data to reproduce your situation:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "date": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    "level": [2., 1., 4.3, 7., 6.5, 8.2, 9.6, 2., 2.1, 3., 4.2, 2]
})
```

To get the mean values of regular intervals from the data in a for loop, you could do something like this:

```py
start = 0     # First row to consider
stop = 11     # Last row to consider
interval = 3  # The desired chunk size

for i in range(start, stop, interval):
    print(df["level"][i:(i + interval)].mean())
    # Or do something else with the means ...
```

```
2.433333333333333
7.233333333333333
4.566666666666666
3.0666666666666664
```

To plot the means you could alter this to:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

means = []
for i in range(start, stop, interval):
    means.append(df["level"][i:(i + interval)].mean())

plt.plot(means)
```